# Spyscroll not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason I'm not being able to make Spyscroll work. Can anyone point out what's the problem? I've been trying to fix it the whole day...

I've tried both the javascript and html+css implementations, but so far none of them have worked. When I put the class "active" on the a manually the css works, but when scrolling the nav is not highlighted.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzxwckzt/)

HTML:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

    <!--==========MENU============-->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#1">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">PROCESS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#4">TEAM</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!--==========CONTENT============-->

    <section class="page" id="1">
    </section>
    <section style="background-color:red" class="page" id="2">
    </section>
    <section class="page" id="3">
    </section>
    <section style="background-color:red" class="page" id="4">
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.nav li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.nav li a:hover {
  color: #00dcbe;
}

.nav li a.active {color:blue;}

.page {height:600px;border:1px solid #000}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Spyscroll to work then you need `.navbar-nav` class to be added to your **ul** like:

```css
    .nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.nav li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.nav li a:hover {
  color: #00dcbe;
}

.nav li a.active {color:blue;}

.page {height:600px;border:1px solid #000}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

    <!--==========MENU============-->

    
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

    

      
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#3">Section 3</a></li>
          
        </ul>

 

</nav>   

    <!--==========CONTENT============-->

  <section class="page" id="1">
  </section>
   <section style="background-color:red" class="page" id="2">
  </section>
   <section class="page" id="3">
  </section>
   <section style="background-color:red" class="page" id="4">
  </section>

  </body>
```

Comment: Can you check what am I doing wrong in my page? Can't fix it even with the suggested corrections. http://trisphera.com

Comment: Because you  have override your bootstrab css classes it does not work. try to remove all the styles related to your nav and ul and it should work.

Comment: It did work by putting the class nav-link on my <a> . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 simple things wrong with your fiddle.  First is that you need to load jquery before you load bootstraps javascript so just drag the jquery to the top of the external resources list.  Then you need to add `navbar-nav` to your `ul` like so:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

Then it works fine.

Here is an updated fiddle [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/8wfmyohx/)

Also if you want your active nav link to have a blue color you will need to first specify it by targeting the `li.acitve` and not the actual `a` tag and you will have to be more specific because of the addition of the `navbar-nav` class because it has additional css that comes stock with bootstrap so you need to specify your css like so:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #00dcbe;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li.active a {
  color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Can you check what am I doing wrong in my page? Can't fix it even with the suggested corrections. http://trisphera.com

Comment: For starters you have boostrap 3 markup and are loading bootstrap 4 css and javascript.  In your fiddle you are linked to bootstrap 3.   In your site you kind of have a mix and match of both bootstrap 3 and 4 markup and are using bootstrap 4 css and js.  You should read the documentation on both and pick one because 3 and 4 are vastly different.  I don't think that is the only issue but I would start there.  I don't have the time to debug your entire site but it is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this for Easy spyscroll -

```
  <div class="navigation-block">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#red" class="active">Red</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#green">Green</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#blue">Blue</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content-block">
    <div class="box-block red" id="red"></div>
    <div class="box-block green" id="green"></div>
    <div class="box-block blue" id="blue"></div>
  </div>



    body{
      margin:0;
    }
    html,body,.content-block,.box-block{
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      display:block;
    }
    .red{
    background:#CF0404;
    }
    .green{
     background:#75890c;
    }
    .blue{
     background:#207ce5;
    }
    *{
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .navigation-block{
      position:fixed;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:100%;
      background:#000;
    }
    .navigation-block ul{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      width:100%;
      list-style:none;
    }
    .navigation-block ul li{
      width:auto;
      float:left;
      margin-right:10px;
    }
    .navigation-block ul li a{
      width:auto;
      float:left;
      color:#fff;
      font-size:18px;
      font-weight:600;
      text-decoration:none;
      font-family:arial;
      padding:10px;
    }

    .navigation-block ul li a.active{
      color:yellow;
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
  window.CP.PenTimer.MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT = 6000;

  $('.navigation-block a').on("click",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      var target = this.hash;
      var $target = $(target);

      $("html, body").stop().animate({
          "scrollTop": $target.offset().top - 40
      }, 600, 'swing', function () {
          // window.location.hash = target;
          history.replaceState(undefined, undefined, target)
      });
      $('.banner-navigation').find('li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).parents('li a').addClass('active');

  });


  // scroll fixed

    function getSections($links) {
      return $(
        $links
          .map((i, el) => $(el).attr('href'))
          .toArray()
          .filter(href => href.charAt(0) === '#')
          .join(','),
      );
    }

    function activateLink($sections, $links) {
      const yPosition = $window.scrollTop();

      for (let i = $sections.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        const $section = $sections.eq(i);

        if (yPosition >= $section.offset().top - 40) {
          return $links
            .removeClass('active')
            .filter(`[href="#${$section.attr('id')}"]`)
            .addClass('active');
        }
      }
    }

    function onScrollHandler() {
      activateLink($sections, $links);
    }

    // Variables
    const $window = $(window);
    const $links = $('.navigation-block li a');
    const $sections = getSections($links);
    const $root = $('html, body');
    const $hashLinks = $('a[href^="#"]:not([href="#"])');

    // Events
    $window.on('scroll', onScrollHandler);
```